# Check if firebase messaging is available in browser

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

I'm planning to use Firebase Messaging in my Angular app using the [@angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) wrapper.

In the original Firebase reference they describe a [firebase.messaging.isSupported() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging#.isSupported), which seems a sensible thing to call when planning to make my app available for various browsers.

Now the @angular/fire wrapper does not expose that method, and, when looking at it's source code, it also does not seem to use it internally.

So my question is: Is it safe to just register the `requestToken` observable of the @angular/fire wrapper, or do I need to make sure that Firebase Messaging is supported by the current browser first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using angular/fire then firebase is a dependency. We're just doing:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  constructor(
     ...
  ) {

    this.messaging = firebase.messaging();

    if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
        ...         
    } else {
        // let the user know their browser doesn't support notifications, probably Safari, eww
    }

  }
```